# chat program as distributed

Tags: java

i have a chat program (as centralized) consist of two part, the first part is the server and the second part is the client.if one client want to participate in the chat,first he must connect to the server,if client need to send a message he will send the message to the server then the server broadcast the message to all the clients that were connected to it.
that was a chat system as centralized

I want to create a chat system as  distributed by using java RMI.how can i do that?
can i let the client connect to the other clients directly?
i want to see your suggestion?
thanks

Comment: How do you plan to solve NATs?

Comment: @m7m: NAT as in [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT)

Comment: @m7m, if both of your users are behind a NAT (as most are), then your peers will not be able to connect to each other without asking your users to poke holes through their firewall.

Comment: Kirk Woll ,do you mean i can not let each client connect to all others clients?

Comment: @m7m, correct, not without their opening up ports in their firewall a la bittorrent clients.